# spring batch schedule chunk of data

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

i am new to spring batch and i have a task that i read chunk from database (100 items) and send it to another data source through kafka topic and this job runs every day, how is that done with chunk-based processing?

what i have done that i created a chunk-based processor and create step

```
    @Bean
        public Step sendUsersOrderProductsStep() throws Exception {
            return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("testStep").<Order, Order>chunk(100)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(orderKafkaSender()).build();
        }
```

and i have created job

```
  @Bean
    Job sendOrdersJob() throws Exception {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob")
            .start(sendUsersOrderProductsStep()).build();
    }
```

but this read the data all once and send to writer chunks until the reader finishes all the data, i want to send every 100 periodically

Answer (score 0):

> but this read the data all once and send to writer chunks until the reader finishes all the data,

That's how the chunk-oriented processing model works, please check the documentation here: [Chunk-oriented Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing).

> i want to send every 100 periodically

You can try to set the maximum number of items in each job run by using `JdbcCursorItemReader#setMaxItemCount` for example.